# Using cvzone HandDetector with a webcam in Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, cvzone

I am working on a Django project that involves using a webcam to play a rock-paper-scissors game against a computer. I have implemented the HandDetector algorithm to detect a hand in the webcam video feed, and a Keras classifier to classify the hand gesture. However, I am running into an issue with getting the HandDetector to work properly with the webcam video.

I have tried using a single still image from the webcam, but the HandDetector does not work well with just one image. I think the solution is to use a video of the hand, but I am not sure how to implement this in my Django project.

Here is the code for my jQuery script that captures the video from the webcam and sends it to a Django view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <video id="webcam" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button id="play-button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="play()">Play</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { startWebcam(); });

var video = document.getElementById('webcam');
var stream;

function startWebcam() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
    .then(function(localMediaStream) {
        stream = localMediaStream;
        video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
        video.play();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
    });
}

function play() {
    // Stop the video stream from the webcam
    var tracks = stream.getTracks();

    for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        var track = tracks[i];
        track.stop();
    }
    // Start recording
    var chunks = [];
    var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    recorder.start();

    // Count down from 3 seconds
    var count = 3;
    var countdown = setInterval(function() {
        $('#countdown').html(count);
        count--;
        if (count === -1) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            recorder.stop();
        }
    }, 1000);

    recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        chunks.push(e.data);
    }

    recorder.onstop = function() {
        // Concatenate all the chunks
        var blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/webm' });
        chunks = [];

        // Send the video to the server
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("video_data", blob);
        formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", '{{ csrf_token }}');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/process-video/',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#result').html(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };
}
</script>
```

Here are the django views I use:

```
def process_video(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponse("Error: Invalid request method")

    # Get the video data from the request
    video_data = request.FILES.get('video_data')

    # Use OpenCV to read the video and extract the frames
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_data)
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            # Process the frame and check for a hand
            prediction = process_image_data(frame)
            if prediction != "Error: No hand detected in the image":
                cap.release()
                return HttpResponse(prediction)
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    return HttpResponse("Error: No hand detected in the video. Please try again.")


def process_image_data(image_data):
    # Initialize the hand detector, image processor, and classifier
    detector = HandDetector(maxHands=1)
    processor = ImageProcessor(detector, 300, 20)
    classifier = HandClassifier()
    # Find the hand in the image
    hands = detector.findHands(image_data, draw=False)

    # If a hand is detected in the image
    if hands:
        hand = hands[0]
        x, y, w, h = hand['bbox']
        img_white, img_resize = processor.process(image_data, hand)
        # Calculate the aspect ratio of the cropped image
        aspect_ratio = h / w
        # If the aspect ratio is greater than 1, add the resized image to the white image
        # with a gap at the top and bottom to center the image
        if aspect_ratio > 1:
            h_gap = math.ceil((300 - img_resize.shape[0]) / 2)
            img_white[h_gap:h_gap + img_resize.shape[0], :] = img_resize
        # If the aspect ratio is less than or equal to 1, add the resized image to the white image
        # with a gap at the left and right to center the image
        else:
            w_gap = math.ceil((300 - img_resize.shape[1]) / 2)
            img_white[:, w_gap:w_gap + img_resize.shape[1]] = img_resize

        # Classify the image and return the prediction
        return classifier.classify(img_white)
    else:
        return "Error: No hand detected in the image"
```

The HandClassifier class

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from keras.models import load_model
import os


class HandClassifier:
    def __init__(self):
        # Get the absolute paths to the model and labels files
        model_path = os.path.abspath('../keras/keras_model.h5')
        labels_path = os.path.abspath('../keras/labels.txt')

        # Load the model and labels
        self.model = load_model(model_path, compile=False)
        with open(labels_path, 'r') as f:
            self.labels = f.read().splitlines()

    def classify(self, image):
        # Resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
        # resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
        image = Image.fromarray(image)
        image.convert('RGB')
        size = (224, 224)
        image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        # Turn the image into a NumPy array
        image_array = np.asarray(image)
        # Normalize the image
        normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1
        # Add the image to the data array
        data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)
        data[0] = normalized_image_array
        # Use the model to make a prediction
        prediction = self.model.predict(data)
        # Get the index of the most likely class
        index = np.argmax(prediction[0])

        # run the inference
        prediction = self.model.predict(data)
        index = np.argmax(prediction)
        class_name = self.labels[index]
        confidence_score = prediction[0][index]

        return class_name
```

And the ImageProcessor class

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


class ImageProcessor:
    def __init__(self, detector, img_size, offset):
        self.detector = detector
        self.img_size = img_size
        self.offset = offset

    def process(self, img, hand):
        # Crop the image based on the bounding box of the detected hand
        x, y, w, h = hand['bbox']
        img_crop = img[y - self.offset:y + h + self.offset, x - self.offset:x + w + self.offset]

        # Convert the image to grayscale
        img_crop = cv2.cvtColor(img_crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Convert the image data to depth 8 bits per pixel
        img_hog = cv2.normalize(img_crop, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

        # Apply median filtering to the image to remove noise
        img_hog = cv2.medianBlur(img_hog, ksize=5)

        # Resize the image to 300x300
        img_crop = cv2.resize(img_hog, (self.img_size, self.img_size))

        # Add a third dimension to the resized image to match the shape of the white image
        img_resize = np.expand_dims(img_crop, axis=2)

        # Create an empty white image of size 300x300
        img_white = np.ones((self.img_size, self.img_size, 3), np.uint8) * 255

        return img_white, img_resize
```

Any help/tips on what would be the best most performant way to do this would be greatly appreciated

I have tried first to send a image taken from the webcam to the views.py but the problem here was that the handdetector never detected any hands. When i try my code out in a test class I wrote it works and classifies the hand live, but this is a live webcam feed in a seperate opencv window. this is the testing class btw

```
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import math

from src.rps.hand_recognition.HandClassifier import HandClassifier
from src.rps.hand_recognition.ImageProcessor import ImageProcessor

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = HandDetector(maxHands=1)
classifier = HandClassifier()

offset = 20
img_size = 300

labels = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"]

while True:
    processor = ImageProcessor(detector, img_size, offset)
    success, img = cap.read()
    hands = detector.findHands(img, draw=False)

    if hands:
        hand = hands[0]
        x, y, w, h = hand['bbox']
        img_white, img_resize = processor.process(img, hand)
        # Calculate the aspect ratio of the cropped image
        aspect_ratio = h / w
        # If the aspect ratio is greater than 1, add the resized image to the white image
        # with a gap at the top and bottom to center the image
        if aspect_ratio > 1:
            h_gap = math.ceil((img_size - img_resize.shape[0]) / 2)
            img_white[h_gap:h_gap + img_resize.shape[0], :] = img_resize

        # If the aspect ratio is less than or equal to 1, add the resized image to the white image
        # with a gap at the left and right to center the image
        else:
            w_gap = math.ceil((img_size - img_resize.shape[1]) / 2)
            img_white[:, w_gap:w_gap + img_resize.shape[1]] = img_resize

        # improve with probability!!!!
        prediction = classifier.classify(img_white)

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x - offset, y - offset - 50),
                      (x - offset + 90, y - offset - 50 + 50), (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.putText(img, prediction, (x, y - 26), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.7, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x - offset, y - offset),
                      (x + w + offset, y + h + offset), (255, 0, 255), 4)

        cv2.imshow("ImageWhite", img_white)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: where's the traceback? [mre] required. -- not an opencv problem. for problems with cvzone, contact author of cvzone. -- if you're asking how to access a local webcam in a django framework project... it helps to learn about the lifecycle of a django app, what functions are called, how threading works, etc

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, I should've made a minimal reproducible example. But it's the first time I'm coding in python and working with django so I thought I'll show the entire code. I'm going to try and use a StreamingHttpResponse instead.

Comment: expect this to be messy. web servers are event driven (server calls your callbacks) while OpenCV VideoCapture has to run continuously or else buffers fill up and data is dropped or the connection (to the camera) is closed due to this exceptional condition. -- if you want to learn django, limit yourself to that first. if you want to learn some image processing, limit yourself to that first. OpenCV has an `imshow()` function. -- moving pictures/video over the web is expensive. especially if you send uncompressed data, or individual pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, it's for a school project where we need to come up with an innovative project (coding in a language we've never coded in before). So it only needs to be a prototype it doesn't need to be perfect, I'm first going to do a little more research also about webrtc. But I want to thank you for your time :)